# Поиск в массиве. Найти наибольшее в строке и наименьшее в столбце

Tags: c++

Дан двумерный массив. Найти наибольшее значение в строке и наименьшее значение в столбце. Написал следующую программу. В чём ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool min_syun(int [],int,int);
bool max_tox(int[],int,int);
void main ()
{
    const int n=3,m=4;
    int a[n][m],c[n],i,j,k=0,l=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            cin>>a[i][j];

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                k++;


            for(l=0;l<n,k<n;l++,k++)
                c[l]=a[k][i];

        if(min_syun(c,a[i][j],n) && max_tox(a[i],a[i][j],m))
        cout<<a[i][j]<<"-"<<k<<endl;
            }
        system("pause");


}
bool min_syun(int a[],int x, int m)
{
    int min,i;
    min=x;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        if(a[i]<min)
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool max_tox(int a[], int x, int n)
{
    int max,i;
    max=x;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(a[i]>max)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Вот чисто интереса ради - как вы считаете, как должно работать условие в этом цикле: `for(l=0;l<n,k<n;l++,k++)`?

Comment: Don't it work in that way???

Comment: Вам уже намекали - по-русски, это все же RU Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Я согласился на переоткрытие, чтобы после перезакрыть с более правильной теперь причиной ;)